# PostgreSQL >= 10 Filtered publications and subscriptions

Tags: postgresql

I have gone nuts searching for information about this. MS SQL offers the option as can be found here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4116/sql-server-transactional-replication-static-row-and-column-filters/ but I could not find a way to do this in Postgres.

This is the case:

- There is a central server storing the information of resources to be consumed locally by other local servers.
- Each of the local servers is interested only in the resources that belongs to it. (i.e. there is a central repository of books, and I only want the books written in my language)
- Additionally as each server is a separate client, there should be a "great wall" to avoid them to access information of other clients.

We have thought of several lines for developing this:

- Use a socket (already implemented) to push changes from central to local via API.
- Use triggers to push changes from central to local on database level.
- Use logic replication as explained in the question.

I also have no information of which method would be more effective computationally or regarding I/O. The table is small, less than 15 columns and less than 10,000 rows. So I guess there should not be a problem. Although updates to this table may happen as several per second (2 or 3 per second estimated average).

Logic replication (Publisher + Subscribers at DB level) seems like the proper solution, but I am stuck.

Ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the built-in logical replication. But you could try [pglogical](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/de/resources/pglogical/) where is is apparently possible.

Comment: I had missed that package, 2 days searching... Seems like what we need. Now under testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package pglogical works for this purpose, as stated by @a_horse_with_no_name

Latency seems good for now, for us, it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with logical replication would be to partition the table by client and replicate only the respective partition.

But with 10000 rows that seems like overkill.

I would enable row level security on the table so that every client can only see the data that belong to them. Then define a foreign table in each client's database and pull the whole thing over.  You can either

- truncate and replace the table every time

or

- if you have foreign key dependencies, first remove the rows that do no longer exist in the central database, then insert or update those rows that are new or were modified

Comment: Additionally to pglogical as stated above, Investigating about row level security. I think I will make a mix of those 2. Will report the solution once tested. Thanks!